# Circumcision of Yishmael's descendants

Tags: gentiles, brit-milah, parashat-lech-lecha, islam

In [Bereishit 17:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#13) we are commanded to circumcise all children born in our households and all servants bought for money, consequently Abraham [performed it](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#23) on Yishmael too. This is [one reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_male_circumcision#Islam) why Muslim boys are circumcised even today.* Should a Muslim person ask it, can a *mohel* circumcise a person of Islamic faith? Can a Jewish person actively look for opportunities to do so by advertising for example?

<sup>* Although in Judaism it is [debated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79696/15256), whether they can be considered descendants of Yishmael.</sup>

Comment: I know a couple of mohelim in training (they are both doctors as well) who "practised" on Muslims

Comment: In the UK the minhag is for mohelim not to charge although one should pay their insurance costs, since there are very many all willing to do it free. So they make their money on moslems. It is not a clear cut heter.

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/11-08-13/

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=16508&rid=15011

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that there would be something wrong with circumcizing non-Jews?

Comment: @Alex Because they might not do it for the sake of mitzvah, but for some avodah zarah instead. Moreover, it's not an universally accepted fact that Muslim people can be regarded as the descendants of Yishmael.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Why should it matter if they are descendants of Yishmael?

Comment: @Alex See the Rambam cited in comment

Comment: The Rambam says the only reason why Yishmaelits are obligated is because bnei ketura are, and they assimilated with each other, so they're obligated in doubt.

Comment: @Kazibácsi That's about whether they are obligated, not about whether it would be problematic if they are not obligated.

Comment: @Alex Muslims, non-Jews, should not practice circumcision, a holy act that signifies who is a Jew. Not to mention that Abraham disowned all the Yishmaelits when he sent Yishmael away.

Answer (score 2):

The [Shaagas Arye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_ben_Asher_Gunzberg) (49) writes that it is permitted to circumcise *Bnei Keturah* and *Bnei Yishmael* who are obligated in circumcision.

However, it is worth noting that not all practicing Muslims are *Bnei Yishmael*. Regarding gentiles who are not obligated in circumcision, there are three opinions:

1. Some authorities rule that one should not circumcise them (outside
   the framework of conversion). [Beis Yosef YD 266, Rema 263:5, Igros
   Moshe YD 2:7].
2. Others rule that it is permitted to circumcise a gentile. [See
   Rambam Milah 3:7, Shach 263:8, Yabia Omer YD 2:19].
3. Some require the circumcision to be performed differently (Maharam
   Shik OC 144), without the *priah*.

---

It is worth noting that Rashi (Sanhedrin 59) and Ramban (Yevamos 46) posit that descendants of Yishmael are not obligated in circumcision. The Rambam (Melachim 10:8) rules that they are obligated. Accordingly, the ruling of the Shaagas Arye is in accordance with the view of the Rambam.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed the Rambam holds the Ishmaelite are obligated to give the children circumcision (also at the age of 8 days). It goes therefore that Halacha obligates it (at least the Rambam, I haven't seen other rishonim) it may certainly be done by a mohel. There is no problem in general of a jew circumcising a gentile, although it is also called an "אות", unlike shabbos which gentiles are forbidden to keep.

Comment: Hi Reb Moishe, welcome to MY and thank you for your answer! Could you please point me to the source where the Rambam says this? Also, why isn't it problematic to circumcise a gentile?

Comment: Rambam argues with Rashi (Sanhedrin 59b), who holds that Yishmaelim are not obligated in Bris Milah but Bnei Keturah are (so the Rambam's safek d'oraisa l'hachmir of Muslims goes the other way according to him; the question is that they might be Bnei Keturah, not that they might be Bnei Yishmael).

Comment: If the Halacha requires someone to be circumcised, how could it be problematic to fulfill that halacha?

Comment: Why does halacha obligates Muslims, non-Jews, to perform the holy act of being a Jew? This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

Even if they are descendants of Yishmael, why should they circumcise? Yishmael was sent away by Abraham. Abraham disowned Yishmael. Yishmael is not Jewish and Muslims pray to Allah, not G-d. They have no right to perform a holy act. It's disgusting.

Comment: As already mentioned in comments. The Rambam says they're chayiv in mila misafek.

Comment: @Shlomy Rashi disagrees. Muslims do not practice Judaism. circumcision is a Jewish practice.

Comment: Rambam was a universalist. That's why he said what he said. He also felt that Islam was not idolatry.

Comment: They argue whether bnei bnei ketura are chayiv in mila... which depends how you learn the gemara in Sanhedrin there...  Besides i hear from people that they say over a Zohar that says the arabs have Israel in the merit of mila... also according to rashi they might still get a kium mitzva for doing mila.