# Do Arabs have a distinct stature among non-Jews as they descend from Abraham?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, abraham, yishmael

To best of my knowledge, according to Judaism, both Arabs and Jews descend from Abraham. In particular, Arabs are believed to be descended from Ishmael, and Jews are believed to be descended from Isaac.

Given that, do Arabs have a special stature among gentiles?

Comment: The Edomites, later Romans, also descend from Abraham.  The only status they have is very negative.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79688/759

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94 הרמב"ם הוסיף שאמנם צאצאי ישמעאל אינם מחויבים במילה מעיקר הדין, אך מאחר שבני ישמעאל התערבו בבני קטורה, בפועל אף בני ישמעאל חייבים למול ביום השמיני

Comment: For the naysayers above, please read Rashi to Bereishis 21:17 CLOSELY... and then please read Devarim 23:8 with a balanced eye... and you will see that we do, indeed, have brotherly feelings towards our brothers...

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Desole,mais je ne peux parler Hebrew.

Comment: @SpiderRico Hebrew is a common source language here on the Judaism StackExchange, I don't think TheGRAPKE was trying to obfuscate. Such as it is, that was a quote from a Wikipedia article anyway, which essentially translates to _Maimonides adds that indeed descendants of Ishmael [Arabs] are not obligated in circumcision by the letter of the law, but since the children of Ishmael mixed with the children of Keturah [Abraham's third wife], in practice even the children of Ishmael are obligated to circumcise on the eighth day._

Comment: @SpiderRico Which means that according to the Rambam they have a significant positive status in Judaism and are part of the Abrahamitic covenant.